# Возвращение неявно приведённого типа из map

Tags: java

Есть

```
Map<Class<?>, AbstractClass> holder = new HashMap<>();
```

Заполняется

```
final Reflections s = new Reflections("reflection.components");
for(Class c : s.getSubTypesOf(AbstractComp.class)) {
    holder.put(c, (AbstractComp) c.newInstance());
}
```

Выводит класс внутри:

```
System.out.println(holder.get(Inner.class).getClass().getSimpleName());
```

Вопрос:
При каждом вызове, мне необходимо получать компонент с его методами посредством явного приведения типов: `(Inner) holder.get(Inner.class)`.
Как мне получить такой вид применения в коде: `holder.get(Inner.class).callMethod()` без явного приведения типов и без проверок на instanceof, ведь java уже знает что внутри лежать subTypes, а значи тесть вариант неявного приведения типов через генерики или ещё что-нибудь, но мне пока не хватает мозга чтобы это осознать.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Всё разобрался! Спасибо всем!
Выход - метод:

```
<T> T get(Class<T> clazz) {
    return (T) holder.get(clazz);
}
```

Comment: вам вроде сильно никто и не помогал)

Comment: вероятно мы тут были той самой резиновой уткой, про это даже кто то писал на мете)